# Adding parameters to SOAP API call from SF by changing WSDL

Tags: api, soap, wsdl, python

I am working on an application using zeep and wsdl to call a SOAP api. The wsdl has a function that is pulling ~15 fields from salesforce, which are later written to a csv file (through python). I need to add a few fields to this request.

Is there any way of checking all the available fields from the api? The relevant complex type looks something like this:

```
<xsd:complexType name="All_Fields">
 <xsd:sequence>
  <xsd:element name="FIELD_1" minOccurs="0" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
  <xsd:element name="FIELD_2" minOccurs="0" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
  <xsd:element name="FIELD_3" minOccurs="0" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
  ...
```

The output csv has these 3 fields. If I add this row to my wsdl underneath Field_3, I get a new column in my csv called Field_4, but it is an empty column

```
<xsd:element name="FIELD_4" minOccurs="0" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
```

As of now, I am unaware of the exact names of the required fields. Would I need to know those, or is there a way of getting a list of all fields being returned in the api response? For now, I have been told the new fields exist in Salesforce (I can't see them in the WSDL though)

If I am entirely on the wrong track, please advise whether this is something that can be done from my end - changing the python/xml files, or if the salesforce api needs to be changed.

I have a targetNamespace at the top of the wsdl file and a soap:address at the end

```
targetNamespace="http://soap.sforce.com/schemas/class/MY_API_NAME" 
soap:address location="https://MYPROJECT.my.salesforce.com/services/Soap/class/MY_API_NAME"
```

Are these links usable to find what data is being returned? Similarly, are these links usable to look at all available parameters etc.?

Comment: Is the web service (and the corresponding WSDL) a dedicated one that has been created for you? The **/services/Soap/class/MY_API_NAME** in the location makes it look like someone is creating a dedicated web service for you in Apex.
The alternative is to use something like the Salesforce Partner API. With that you can query the fields that are exposed to you.